# Reseting a cooldown of a command in discord.py

Tags: python, pycharm, discord

I have been trying to figure out if there is some thing in discord.py or python that would reset a cooldown of a command if the command is returned. For example (as you can see below) someone types `!math` but if there is another command running, the command wont proceed and the user has to wait 60 seconds again because the command is on cooldown.

Code just for example:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60.00, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def math(msg):
    if msg.channel.id != channel:
        return
    if another_command_running:
        await msg.send(msg.author.mention + " Another command is running")
        return
    ....
    ....
    ....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cooldown can be reset with Discord's build in feature: `reset_cooldown`, in your case, it will reset the math command cooldown so the user would be able to use it instantly again.

Simply append the to the point where the command should have it's cooldown removed.

```
math.reset_cooldown(ctx)
```